# Парсинг stdClass

Tags: php

Есть строка, `var_dump()` которой показывает:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["response"]=> int(112) }
```

Как мне добраться до поля `112`?

Полный код:

```
$ress = sendMessege($text, $user_id);

function sendMessege($text, $id) {
    $url = "https://api.....";
    $data = curlGet($url);
    return $data;
}

function curlGet($url) {   
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: стрелочкой, как в классах: ->response

Comment: Я сейчас буду экстрасенсом но когда делаете `json_encode($json,true)`, ставьте последний параметр для преобразования в массив, и работайте с ним.

Comment: @zhenyab ответ то опубликуйте

Comment: а это тянет на ответ?

Comment: Стрелочкой возвращает NULL

Comment: покажите полностью весь ваш код

Comment: Обновил вопрос  .............

Comment: stdClass в PHP это вроде анонимного класса. Если в нем прописано это свойство, значит должно показывать. $ress->response - так Вы сделали?

Comment: да  $ress->response возвращает NULL

Comment: Вы не весь код привели так как ответ от curl приходит в виде текста где то вы преобразуете его или парсите. Плюс не вижу надобности в curl `file_get_contents($url)` заменит вам всё.

Comment: var_dump($ress) что выдает?

Answer (score 1):

Вы получили ответ в в виде объекта: `$data->response`
Для того чтобы ответ конвертировать в массив, попробуйте: `$ret = (array)$data;`

Comment: Конвентировать получилось, и $ret[0] дает {"response":129}, но $ret[0]['response'] пишет Warning: Illegal string offset 'response'

Comment: @antonin14d как параметр класса должно работать можно для примера сдесь посмотреть http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/666028897eab22984d664572ece9bb6992c3c83b

Answer (score -3):

Если я правильно понял, то это у вас массив, Я думаю можно обратиться вот так

```
$stdClass["response"]
```

Comment: в php 5.4 пишет, несовместимо с версией php

Comment: Это объект у него а не массив, по этому и downvote